# Opening/loading layer file in ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-pro, layer-file

I ran a script for [location allocation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/location-allocation.htm) on ArcPy, which worked.

After running it, I used the [Save to Layer File](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/save-to-layer-file.htm) to save the result.

Now that I have the result saved (and can even open on ArcMap), I want to reload that file into a Python script to do some work on it.

How do I load/read/open the layer file into Python again? Basically the reverse process of Save to Layer File, where you input a file path and it outputs a object that is the results layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcGIS Desktop 10.x you use [`arcpy.mapping.Layer`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm)

```
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"path\to\file.lyr")
print lyr.name
```

In ArcGIS Pro you use [`arcpy.mp.LayerFile`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layerfile-class.htm):

```
lyrFile = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(r"path\to\file.lyrx")
for lyr in lyrFile.listLayers():
    print(lyr.name)
```